# Causes of traffic drop in direct channel

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

Direct traffic in google analytics dropped in my site by 25% (around 100,000 users) in less than 2 weeks.

Please help me in listing possibilities behind that loss

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to? Year on year? Previous period? Do you see an increase in other channels or are they stable/the same/lower? This is important to know to exclude seasonality or organic/paid search combinations for users (e.g. when there's a large drop in organic or paid traffic, direct traffic will most likely follow).

Considering the scenario that all your other channels except referrals are stable, and there's no seasonality involved, it most likely sounds like a problem with the referrer header not being passed.

- http to http – Referral data sent
- http to https – Referral data sent
- https to https – Referral data sent
- https to http – No referral data sent and traffic is attributed to
  direct

Let's say you updated your website to force https. In the previous situation, you would get traffic from https to http, and no referral data would be sent. In the new situation, you would get traffic from https to https—the referral data is sent and attributed to the right channel in Google Analytics instead of the traffic being attributed to direct. This in turn causes a drop in direct traffic.